# Destructuring object allows to assign incorrect value to typed variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's say there are two interfaces:

```
interface S {
  s: string
}

interface AB {
  a?: S[],
  b?: number
}
```

We can create a constant of type S and unassigned variable ab:

```
const constS: S = { s: 'const' }
let ab: AB
```

Normally we would assign something like this if we wanted to use value of constant `constS`:

```
ab = { a: [constS], b: 1 }
```

Now the question is why TypeScript allows to assign a value to variable `ab` that is not of type `AB` when using destructuring (spread operator) like this:

```
ab = { ...constS, b: 1 }
```

If we log `ab` now we get: `{ s: 'const', b: 1 }`, but trying to assign this value to `ab` Typescript, correctly, throws an exception:

```
> ab = { s: 'const', b: 1 }
error TS2322: Type '{ a: string; b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'AB'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 's' does not exist in type 'AB'.
```

but the variable even has the value we're trying to assign.

Side note, trying to assign `ab = { ...constS }` throws `Type '{ s: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'AB'`.

Why TS allows for this behavior and how can I prevent object `ab` from having properties not in its type?

Comment: [Excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) is more of a linter rule than a type safety rule; object types in TypeScript are generally allowed to have excess properties. Indeed this is what enables interface extension and structural subtyping in general.  The fact that spreading does not trigger excess property checking is intentional, see [ms/TS#43964](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43964) for example. You cannot truly *prevent* any object from having extra properties.

Comment: You could go through a lot of extra trouble to try to make it less likely, but it would be much better if you just try to make sure your code does not depend on the absence of unknown properties.  If that makes sense to you I could write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I see that object types are unstrict, but still I can't understand what's the reason for allowing the spread operator to introduce excess properties? I mean, in the example even if `ab` has property `s` I still cannot access it because it's not on its type.

Comment: Also, do you know if for example ESlint could give me a warning in this situation?

Comment: I know it’s working as intended, but it’s not obvious *why* it is intended that way.  My strong suspicion is that excess property checking only prevents situations in which properties will be completely unobservable, even from other objects.  When you spread from another object, the other object still exists and you can access properties from it. This implies that spreading from object *literals* should give warnings (e.g., `{…{a:1}}`) but it doesn’t.  So ‍♂️ (there is an open issue about that though I think).

Comment: ( https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39998 is the open issue )

Answer (score 0):

The spread `...` operator is runtime construct and completely bypasses the compiler. TypeScript isn’t smart enough to know what this does because it is not explicitly typed and allows it. This is legacy from the fact JavaScript allows duck typing and TypeScript reverts to legacy when it has no insight into the type.

Comment: Well, `constS` that is being spread have type `S`, so I think TS could potentially check if the spread object matches types. The question is why doesn't it check that?